# rails3 rake does not run my tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rake

In a fresh R3 app, I seem to be unable to run any tests (there are 2, the canonical functional test for "/" and another unit test I created)

See this output:

```
rails_app$ rake test --trace
(in /Users/jan/portfolio/rails_app)
** Invoke test (first_time, not_needed)
rails_app$
```

What could be wrong? What is the meaning of first_time, not_needed'?
t might have to do with the fact, that I am using Mongoid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I followed the instructions for Mongoid's installation, I replaced

```
require 'rails/all'
```

with

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
```

after learning about (and inserting)

```
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

tests started to get picked up

Comment: Cannot remember, I am sorry. These days I am using FactoryGirl for these and they just work.